# Why do I keep seeing CAPTCHA?

Tags: support

Everytime I want to answer a question I need to fill CAPTCHA. I already answered 4 questions here and I also have account on other StackExchange sites. Does the system still think I'm not a human?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear) could be of some use. Not sure if you can find exact triggers for CAPTCHA, I assume devs keep some of them under wraps. Maybe you took too long to write your posts? FWIW I haven't seen a CAPTCHA in ages.

Comment: I have *never* seen a CAPTCHA (even before I was a diamond).

Comment: I've seen them very occasionally.  Maybe it's some event trigger - the speed at which you post, or if you view several posts really fast or something.

Comment: I've seen them when I've submitted multiple edits in short succession. Like when I'm editing several tags to have the same standard wording. But again I haven't had one for months now I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

A CAPTCHA can be guaranteed if an A is prepared outside the sandbox (say Word or Notepad) and then copy/pasted in with "Post Your Question" clicked soon after.

<strike>Whether that *is* the cause for OP we can't be sure without further details (which I doubt will be forthcoming since OP seems not to have visited for eight+ months) so there seems little more to be said.</strike>

OP visited 17 days ago, so just seems not interested.